# Why can the std::cout display value less than the minimum value of a float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

**Code:**

```cpp
float a = exp(-88);
cout << a << endl;
cout << numeric_limits<float>::min() << endl;
```

**Ouput:**

```
6.0546e-39
1.17549e-38
```

Can someone explain to me how `std::cout` gets to output a value less than the minimum value of a float?

Comment: How do you get three lines of output from this code?

Comment: @Stef Sorry that was a mistake.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using an exp function that returns floats? std::exp returns both floats and doubles. Double is 8 bytes and has higher precision.

Comment: The magic word is "denormal".

Comment: @deadbird11 Yes, I have the same problem with `expf` function.

Comment: Try [std::numeric_limits<T>::denorm_min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/denorm_min)